# Create JSP with XML Through an Array

Tags: java, xml, arrays, jsp, javabeans

After creating a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse, I created some JavaBean classes and for each class a JSP file, which will return an XML.

Such as:

The bean:

```
package com.beans;
public class Program {
    private String programID = "123";
    private String programName = "Morning show";
    private String startTime = "1365238800";
    private String endTime = "1365242400";
    public String getProgramID() {
        return this.programID;
    }
    public String getProgramName() {
        return this.programName;
    }
    public String getStartTime() {
        return this.startTime;
    }
    public String getEndTime() {
        return this.endTime;
    }
}
```

The Jsp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<%@ page contentType="text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1" %>
<jsp:useBean id="programXML" class="com.beans.Program"/>
<Program>
    <ProgramName><% out.print(programXML.getProgramID()); %></ProgramName>
    <ProgramType><% out.print(programXML.getProgramName()); %></ProgramType>
    <startTime><% out.print(programXML.getStartTime()); %></startTime>
    <endTime><% out.print(programXML.getEndTime()); %></endTime>
</Program>
```

The server returns the following example for the `http://localhost:8080/Project/Program.jsp` request:

```
 <Program>
  <ProgramName>123</ProgramName> 
  <ProgramType>Morning show</ProgramType> 
  <startTime>1365238800</startTime> 
  <endTime>1365242400</endTime> 
  </Program>
```

Which is the XML I expected. Now, I would like to modify the bean/jsp file to receive an XML which contains arrays too, like the following structure:

```
<ProgramList>
 <Program>
   ...
 </Program>
 <Program>
 ...
 </Program>
</ProgramList>
```

Can you give me advices how to modify the bean/jsp?

Comment: If the goal is to return XML, why not use a marshalling framework like JAXB, which would automatically transform your beans into XML, without any need for a JSP?

Comment: The main idea is to create a java server, which will return a specific xml structure for an URL client request. It's important to return through URL request and to be an XML. I just found this method as one possible solution, so any advice is welcomed :)

Comment: My advice is thus to use a marshalling framework such as JAXB which will automatically transform your beans into XML without any need for a JSP.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'll try that framework, seems to be very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should create another Bean called `ProgramList` that contains just an `ArrayList<Program>`.

```
public class ProgramList {

  private ArrayList<Program> list;

  public ArrayList<Program> getList() {
    return this.list;
  }
  public void setList(ArrayList<Program> list) {
    this.list = list;
  }
}
```

Then you can use JSTL forEach in your JSP to print the list of Programs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<%@ page contentType="text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<jsp:useBean id="programList" class="com.beans.ProgramList"/>
<ProgramList>
  <c:forEach var="program" items="${programList.list}">
    <Program>
      <ProgramName>${program.programID}</ProgramName>
      <ProgramType>${program.programName}</ProgramType>
      <startTime>${program.startTime}</startTime>
      <endTime>${program.endTime}</endTime>
    </Program>
  </c:forEach>
</ProgramList>
```

Find [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html) a JSTL tutorial if you're not familiar with it.

Comment: And what about the JSP file? I should give only a xlm.getProgramlist method request and it will return the correct structure?

Comment: I've edited again to improve the code accessing the fields through JSTL as well...

Comment: Thank you MikO, I'm importing it in my project and hopefully it will  work (just fighting with some unknown tags - however I've imported the jstl library). Thanks again :)

Comment: You should use `<c:out value="${program.programName}"/>`, unless you're absolutely sure the attribute will never contain a character that must be XML-escaped (like `<` or `>` for example)

Comment: @JBNizet completely right. I've also added a link to Java EE JSTL tutorial.